# Programmatically adding fields to node submission form

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I need to add fields to a node creation/editing form programmatically. More specifically, I need to take already-generated form elements from another form and insert them into the node submission form.

That part isn't what's hanging me up though. My problem is that I can't figure out how to make the database hang onto the values submitted via the new field.

For example, the following code (copypasta'd directly from the [API Quickstart page](http://drupal.org/node/751826)) creates a form element inside the existing node form just fine, but when I enter a value and submit the form, the value is not stored.

```
function [mymodule]_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['foo'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('bar'),
      '#default_value' => t('foo'),
      '#size' => 60,
      '#maxlength' => 64,
      '#description' => t('baz'),
    );
}
```

How do I alter an existing form in such a way that the submitted values 'take,' so to speak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hacked together a way of doing this. I have NO IDEA whether this is at all a good idea, or if I'm doing something blatantly terrible, so any code or ideas here are for information purposes only!

So, here's what I did (for a module called "webformta")

1. On my content type "Answer Key" I added a text field with unlimited multiple values enabled.
2. Inside `webformta_form_alter()` I add my fields:

   ```
       $form['foo'] = array(
         '#type' => 'textfield',
         '#title' => t('bar'),
         '#default_value' => t('foo'),
         '#size' => 60,
         '#maxlength' => 64,
         '#description' => t('baz'),
       );
    # ... and so forth for all the form elements as I want to add.
   ```
3. Then, after I add the form elements I want, still inside `webformta_form_alter()`:

   ```
       $form['#submit'][] = 'webformta_answerkey_submit';
   ```
4. Next, a separate submit function:

(This appends the responses given onto the ones already in the field without overwriting or deleting the old ones because the `[]` after `$form['#submit']` above adds this onto the `$form['submit']` array instead of replacing it.)

```
function webformta_answerkey_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $foo = $form_state['input']['foo'];
    $values = $form_state['values']['field_answer_answers']['und'];
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($values as $value){
        $count += 1;
    }
    $form_state['values']['field_answer_answers']['und'][$count]['value'] = $foo;
    $form_state['values']['field_answer_answers']['und'][$count]['_weight'] = $count;
}
```

So, the values entered by your user in as many fields as you want can be stored in an array as one field with many values on the node submission form.

Anyone know if this is a terrible idea for any reason?

Answer (score 3):

Add something like this to your `hook_form_alter()`.

```
$form['#submit'] += array('mymodule_another_submit_handler');
```

Create that function and save your values from `$form_state['values']`.

```
function mymodule_another_submit_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {}
```

Where are they supposed to go? You might try to fire the submit handler of the other form so you wouldn't have to write so much code.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to save them as part of the node, as it would save fields that were entered on the content type editing interface.

Comment: another node type, right ?

Comment: I just want to save the input as part of the node that's created by the node creation form upon which these custom fields appear. Also, does the `function my_module_my_form_submit()` declaration go inside `hook_form_alter()`, or outside of it?

Comment: so every node will have a different fieldset, even though they are the same type ? I am not sure you can acheive that ... Did you consider conditional fields ? (http://drupalmodules.com/module/conditional-fields) . And the new function would go outside - as any other function in your module.

Comment: I'm not using fieldsets, but yes they would all have different fields with different values even though they are the same type. I don't think conditional fields offers integration with fields that are on a different node, does it?

Comment: but i dont think you could actually save the data into fields that arent defined on that content type ... so you would have to define everything on one content type and use conditional fields. Or save the other node type along with the first one.

Comment: I think you may be right. I'm starting a [new question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33996/is-this-possible-dynamically-changing-fieldsets-on-node-creation) for this issue.

Comment: custom submit handlers need to look a little different.  See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223342/add-a-custom-submission-handler-to-a-form

Comment: @SelwynPolit this was back in D7 :) i added the 7 tag to the question to make it clear for anyone who would stumble upon this now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code just defines a form element. If you want to put the submitted value into the DB you have add a submitthandler and write appropriate code for it.

Maybe you consider adding a field to this node type as this does all the DB numbo jumbo for you for free. No coding would be required at all.

Comment: Yes, I see that it just defines a form element. That is my problem. How would I add a submit handler to an already-extant node submission form? All the examples I have found show only how to make a new one from scratch. I am doing it in code because I need to add different elements to different forms depending on the value of other forms.

Comment: The submit handler field of the form takes an array, the submit handlers are called in the order of the array.

Comment: Is there documentation on the details of how to do that? I can't find anything except a tutorial for Drupal 5 (I'm using 7)

Comment: Not sure, have a look at the implementation of the login form.