# How to create a custom content type with a form

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a custom form. How would I go about creating a content type which calls the form? I have read several tutorials on creating content types, but I do not see how to include my form inside of them.

I am using drupal 7

Thanks in advance

Comment: Bit more information needed. Where have you created the form? What does it do?

Comment: I created it inside of a custom module using the Forms Api. It makes a request to an external Api and then I render that data to the page.

Comment: Ah I see, you can either create your own admin page for the form, or use hook_form_alter() to add fields to the content type form.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33981/programmatically-adding-fields-to-node-submission-form

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7.x also seems to be what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am still having a hard time understanding this. I have posted a new, better explained question [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211116/how-to-insert-a-form-into-a-custom-content-type)