# Installing/Enabling Custom Webform Hander

Tags: 8, webforms

I am very new to Drupal development though I am an experienced developer.  I created a custom Webform Handler following these tutorials and postings:

These for what files to create and where:

[Create a custom webform handler in Drupal 8](https://industrialagency.ca/blog/create-custom-webform-handler-drupal-8)

[Create a Webform Handler that sends a notification to Slack](https://www.lilengine.co/articles/webform-handler)

[Add a custom submission handler to a form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223342/add-a-custom-submission-handler-to-a-form)

This post for the code to redirect a user to another webform upon form submission:

[Page redirect in custom WebformHandlerBase](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245285/page-redirect-in-custom-webformhandlerbase)

I have looked at everything and everything looks correct.  Here's what's in the YAML file modules\custom\redirect_to_ccbilling\redirect_to_ccbilling.info.yml:

```
name: 'Redirect to CC Billing'
description: 'Provides a custom webform handler for the "submit an event" webform so it will redirect to another webform node'
core_version_requirement: ^8.8
Core: 8.x
package: Custom
type: module
```

Here's what's in the modules\custom\redirect_to_ccbilling\src\Plugin\WebformHandler\RedirectToCCBillingWebformHandler.php:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\redirect_to_ccbilling\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Serialization\Yaml;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\src\WebformSubmissionInterface;

/**
 * Form submission handler.
 *
 * @RedirectToCCBilling(
 *   id = "Redirect to CC Billing",
 *   label = @Translation("Redirect to CC Billing"),
 *   category = @Translation("Webform Handler"),
 *   description = @Translation("Redirect user to the credit card billing page."),
 *   cardinality = 
 *       \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_SINGLE,
 *   results = 
 *    \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 * )
 */

 class RedirectToCCBillingWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {
 /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {

       $form_id = 'webform_submission_' . $webform_submission->getWebform()->id() . '_form';
       if($form_id == 'webform_submission_xxx_form') {
         $values = $webform_submission->getData();  
         /* Take the action based on the Webform submission values */   
       }    
    }

    public function confirmForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
       $form_id = 'webform_submission_' . $webform_submission->getWebform()->id() . '_form';
       if($form_id == 'webform_submission_xxx_form')
       {
          if(based_on_some_condition) {
          /* Here 12 is the node id where i wanted to redirect to */
          $form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical',['node' => 1764]);
       }
    }
}   
?>
```

I went into the Extend menu and under Custom section I selected the Redirect to CC Billing module/handler and clicked Install at the bottom of the page.  However, when I go back to my webform >> setting >> emails / handlers >> +add handler all I see is this:

[image]

I don't know what I am missing for my custom handler to not be appearing in the list of handlers.

Comment: For the plugin to be discovered you need to place it in a `WebformHandler` subfolder (might be a typo because there is only one `/` missing) and start the annotation with `* @WebformHandler(`, not the custom id.

Comment: Ah yes, the folder path was just a typo.  I copy/pasted the folder structure and typed the filename but forgot to type a \ first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things in addition to what @4k4 commented:

1. Please replace your annotation plugin reference with `@WebformHandler`
2. Use lower case / snake case names for your Webform Handler ID eg. `redirect_to_ccbilling`
3. Ensure correct directory structure where the plugin discovery will look for Webform Handler classes. This should be `/modules/custom/redirect_to_ccbilling/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/RedirectToCCBillingWebformHandler.php`
4. Ensure that your module is enabled. Either via `drush en redirect_to_ccbilling -y` or by enabling it on the Extend module page.

```
/**
 * Form submission handler.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "redirect_to_ccbilling",
 *   label = @Translation("Redirect to CC Billing"),
 *   category = @Translation("Webform Handler"),
 *   description = @Translation("Redirect user to the credit card billing page."),
 *   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_SINGLE,
 *   results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 * )
 */
class RedirectToCCBillingWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {
```

Comment: Ok, so I made those changes so that the annotation plugin reference is @WebformHandler and the change the Webform Handler ID to "redirect_to_ccbilling".  Being very new to Drupal I actually don't know how/where to execute step 4 for enabling the module.  I have been going to the Extend page in Drupal, selecting the module and then clicking Install at the bottom of the page.  Is that not the same thing.  If not, I need to request RDC to the server as I assume that drush command is something I need to do in a command line.

Comment: Also, the reason I had changed the annotation plugin reference is due to a problem I had before changing it which has now returned once changing it back.  When I go to the emails / handlers page for my webform and click +Add Handler, I get the wheel spin but the handler popup doesn't open.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't intend to confuse you. What you did is absolutely fine by going to that page. The command I shared is just an alternative to do it via the cli. I'll update my answer

Comment: A spinning wheel usually happens because of an Ajax error. I suggest you open your network tab and look for any 500 errors, or look in your syslog / watchdog (dblog) after that happens.

Comment: You may also need to clear caches in between changing those things.

Comment: Ahh, awesome.  Ok so 2 things were wrong in the RedirectToCCBillingWebformHandler.php file.  It was missing the closing "}" for the class and in my attempts to get the +Add Handler to work I had added the "src" folder in the use statement for the WebformSubmissionInterface.  Got that from this link: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2857904.  So the "}" caused an AJAX error and once I fixed that I got the 500 error and found that link .. thanks @baikho