# Which hook can I use before or after submitting a webform form?

Tags: hooks, webforms

I created a webform form with drupal 8.

I would like to populate a database table with information from my form before or after submitting.

I guess there must be a hook like hook_webform_pressave () or hook_webform_insert () but I have not found the solution.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, if you can't find a webform specific solution like answered by @sonfd, the entity hooks you've mentioned should work. Submissions are stored in the entity `webform_submission`, so a hook would be named like this `mymodule_webform_submission_presave()`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the answer to [Add a custom submission handler to a form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223342/add-a-custom-submission-handler-to-a-form). This will tell you how to add a submit handler to a form. You can use the same approach to add a custom submit handler to the webform and then perform the operations you want from the submit handler.