# Renaming a webform handler - old class stuck in DB despite clearing cache

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm creating a custom webform handler plugin based on the [advice here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/238907/68872), adding the class, in the correct directory, to an existing module.

I got the class name / some of the docblock info wrong initially - and need to change it.  Having run `drush cr`, the listing on  */admin/structure/webform/config/handlers* seems to be stuck on the old entry.

I get **"Cannot declare class ... because the name is already in use"** errors when trying to add the handler to the form, for a class name that I'm no longer using, and which, having cleared the cache, definitely isn't in  `cache_discovery.webform_handler_plugins` in the DB.

I've also swapped browsers.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried restarting PHP or the server? This happens to me in local dev sometimes and rebooting the VM seems to work.

Comment: @Kevin ah thanks - restarting the docker container (devwithlando/php:7.1-fpm) worked.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, especially with a local dev environment, after you have tried every other route the only other avenue is to restart the PHP service and/or reboot the server/VM. This should clear system caches and often times will resolve this issue.