# Prevent redirection after comment submission

Tags: 8, theming, forms

When a user add a comment on a node, I would like to prevent the page reload.

I added a form_alter in my theme

```
function theme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch($form_id) {
      case 'my_form_id':
        $form_state['redirect'] = false;
      break;
  }
}
```

But this is not working.

I also tried to replace $form_state['redirect'] = false by $form_state['redirect'] = false but it seems to be the Drupal 7 way to do this.

how could I achieve that on Drupal 8 ?

EDIT

I tried to use a submission handler

```
function theme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        switch($form_id) {
          case 'my_form_id':
            $form['#submit'][] = 'theme_form_submit';
          break;
      }
    }

function theme_form_submit(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $form_state->disableRedirect();
}
```

But it's still not working.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`FormStateInterface::disableRedirect()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3AdisableRedirect/8.2.x), e.g.

```
$form_state->disableRedirect();
```

Make sure you run that code in a submit handler for the form, not in the form alter hook.

Comment: I also tried this one but it didn't changed a thing. Do I need to import something to be able to use it ? (I didn't import anything since no error was rendered)

Comment: I was just detailing the replacement for `$form_state['redirect'] = false`, re-reading your question there's a chance you actually want to install a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments. Adding a comment submits a form, which isn't a redirect, it's a standard POST request. To stop that happening you'll need to implement the same functionality in AJAX

Comment: Just replacing $form_state['redirect'] = false by $form_state->disableRedirect(); would be enough for me if it prevent redirection after submission.
But it's currently not working, maybe because I need to import FormStateInterface, is it necessary ?

But I will still give a look at that module

Comment: I just noticed you're running the code in hook_form_alter - you need to run it in a submit handler for the form. Other submit handlers (core and contrib ones) run after the form alter upon submission, nuking your change. You need to disable the redirect after those have run

Comment: No you don't need to import any namespaces - if you were trying to use something that was unavailable PHP would let you know about it in certain terms

Comment: So this disableRedirect should be called in the hook theme_my_form_id_submit ? Am I correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that convention is still in D8; I prefer `$form['#submit'][] = 'foo';` in the form alter personally

Comment: So replacing $form_state['redirect'] = false; by $form['#submit'][] = $form_state->disableRedirect(TRUE); ?

Comment: No add a submit handler (function) to the form, run the code in there. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223342/add-a-custom-submission-handler-to-a-form for example

Comment: I tried to had a submission handler with `$form['#submit'][] ` but it is not working

Comment: Try `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mysubmit_function';`

Comment: Not working either

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you, that's the tested and documented way to cancel a form redirect. Maybe you need to debug the code to find out how (and if) that redirect actually occurs in the first place