# hook_form_form_id_alter doesn't save data by default

Tags: 8, forms

I use `hook_form_form_id_alter()` to edit the `user_form`. I'm creating some checkboxes and textfields. Thats working fine. I also can output the values, when clicking the submit button.

But it doesn't save the values by default.

How do I save my values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`hook_form_form_id_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.6.x) only alters the form object for *presentation / behavioral changes* on existing forms. It doesn't alter *processing or storage* for existing forms.

For that you'll need to [add a custom submission handler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223342/add-a-custom-submission-handler-to-a-form), or use the Form UI to create new custom user fields if you don't need custom processing/storage needs.